# Navigating to destination between graphs

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

The official demo [NavigationAdvancedSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample)) shows a workaround handling multiple stacks.

Briefly, it demos 3tabs: `Home`, `Leaderboard`, `Register`, every tab has its own graph. Leaderboard Tab graph has two fragments, `Leaderboard` as `startDestination` which has a list of items, click the item will navigate to the `UserProfile` fragment.

In this case, is it possible to navigate from Home tab to UserProfile directly? According to the docs, it looks impossible.

> Destinations outside of the nested graph, such as those on the root graph, access the nested graph only through its start destination.
>   https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs

The workaround I am thinking is to define a destination variant:

Home item click -> Leaderboard (pass destination variant to here) -> UserProfile

But it causes problems and not straight forward.
Any better solution? Thanks